# NVM breaks sporadically because of resetting PREFIX environment variable

Tags: react-native, zsh, nvm

### **The Problem**

I am trying to run a react-native iOS application from the CLI. This has not been a problem in the past, but haven't developed in react-native for over 6 months. Last week in about 40% of the cases when a (zsh) terminal is opened `nvm` breaks because of the environment variables. This could happen whether I open the terminal myself, or when VSCode opens a new terminal for the metro bundler. Running from Xcode always works. Closing all zsh terminals and then opening a new one seems to resolve the issue. Additionally, it happens (more) often in the terminal that is opened by VSCode for the metro bundler than when I open the terminals myself. Lastly, the issue seems to 'stick' once it starts occurring I need to close all terminals for the error to be resolved.

**Error that is shown**

```
nvm is not compatible with the "PREFIX" environment variable: currently set to "/usr/local"
Run `unset PREFIX` to unset it.
nvm is not compatible with the "PREFIX" environment variable: currently set to "/usr/local"
Run `unset PREFIX` to unset it.
```

---

### **What I have tried**

1. Changing environment variables

---

***1.1 When the zsh terminal does NOT show the error:***

I tried running `npm config delete prefix`, in hopes of changing the config so that the issue does not pop up anymore. I can't run this command when the error is shown, because I have no access to node or npm.

***1.2 When the zsh terminal does show the error:***

I can 'fix' the terminal by unsetting the PREFIX variable with `unset PREFIX` and then asking `nvm` to use a version of node. However this only fixes that particular instance of the terminals. The only sure fire way is to close all terminals.

```
unset PREFIX
nvm use v14.15.0
```

2. Updating react-native

---

Speaks for itself, a colleague mentioned that it might be caused by a bug in react-native. Did not resolve the issue unfortunately.

---

### **Conclusion**

It seems as though something (re)triggers setting the PREFIX environment variable when I try to run the react-native iOS project. I am honestly completely lost as to what might be causing this and any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, [as have others](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1645).

Are you using `yarn` or `npm` to run the React Native CLI? If so, and these were installed with Homebrew, these might be conflicting with your `nvm` installed node. Try removing these:

```sh
brew uninstall yarn
brew uninstall npm
```

This should leave behind the version of `npm` that was installed with `nvm`, check this by running:

```sh
which npm
```

This should return a path pointing to your local `.nvm` installation. If it shows `/usr/local` then it was not removed correctly, you might need to follow the [npm removal instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/removal).

Once this is done, if you use `yarn` then install it with `npm`:

```sh
npm install -g yarn
```

Run the React Native CLI once again, it should now work.

More details on this resolution: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1645#issuecomment-850376572